# What are the advantages of heterologous expression systems?

Tags: cell-biology, protein-expression

I am doing research in a lab and I am relatively new to wet lab work. Many experiments that people are doing in my lab include overexpressing a protein of interest from another species (e.g. mouse) into CHO cells via transfection. I have learnt that these are examples of heterologous expression systems.

I was wondering in general, what are the advantages of heterologous expression systems? I have read that you can use them to study the function of a protein in a well-defined, controllable environment. However, I was wondering what other benefits/uses are there to these kinds of experiments?

Any insights are appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- It takes significant resources to establish a cell line. More efficient to use existing lines.
- Often cell lines used for expression grow faster. This is why so many proteins are expressed in E coli - they only take a day to grow vs the week or two for mammalian cells, meaning you get a much faster learning iteration in your research.

Answer (score 1):

To add on @ user47696’s answer, heterologous expression systems also enable [large-scale production](https://www.hindawi.com/journals/ijpg/2009/296482/) of recombinant proteins, particularly in the E. coli and the yeast systems. Foreign hosts may also provide a system that is simpler than the natural sources for the studies on proteins' functions.